# User profile WP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, user-profile

I want to make an Windows Phone application, I have made a couple before but never anything real big. I want to need to make a user profile, not really sure if I have to though if you guys have a better way of doing something.

For example, I want the user to be able to enter something like a phone number and then then the app will display a page about that phone number and the user can leave comments on that page. Would a user profile be best for this? The user will need a user profile, but will the phone number?

I have searched Google on how to do this, and nothing is coming up. I am not sure if I am wording it wrong or what but I can't find a single thing. I am not sure if there is a better way of doing it..like if I need a user profile or not.

I am not looking for you guys to give me the code or anything like that, I am just looking for some help and maybe point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what's your goal? An app that people can use to rate telephone numbers? Something to identifiy e.g. harassing advertising calls?

Comment: @khlr Yes! I know there is stuff out there like that, but this is how I learn, the more I do it and actually go to it the better I learn! I don't know if it is the best way of doing it but yeah

Answer (score 0):

This answer is quite broad and not very concrete, but maybe it gives you an idea:

Besides your wp app you'll at least need a service with a backend-database and host it somewhere to store the telephone numbers and their ratings.

You could then allow your users to rate these numbers anonymously or leave comments anonymously. So until this point you don't necessarily need user profiles.

If you want your users to be able to see a list of telephone numbers they already rated, if you want your users to only be able to rate a number once and so forth you'll need user profiles (although there might be still other ways to reject mutliple actions, e.g. based on IP address).

For that you'll need a way for the user to create a profile, choose a username and password and so on. On the other hand you could offer the ability for the user to log on with her existing facebook or twitter account. Maybe have a look [at this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on).

Comment: I figured I would at least need a database but this confirms that! When you use a Windows Phone I do believe I had to set up a Live account when I got myn, What you just showed me uses Facebook/Twitter authentication. I could probably also use Live somehow and use that as their profile. When I made this post I was thinking of them making their own profile, not using authentication but this is also another way to go.

Comment: Twitter and facebook are just examples. A live-account will be fine, too. Using 3rd party authentication is a nice thing, whereas having your own user authentication might be the easier option from a starting perspective.